# Не могу вывести пагинацию WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Я создал страницу новостей, как обычную страницу с помощью шаблона

```
/* Template Name: Шаблон новости */
```

На ней я вывожу все посты с определённой рубрики, и мне нужно на этой странице сделать пагинацию. Я попробовал вставить стандартную функцию `the_posts_pagination()`, но ничего не произошло. В настройках указал показывать 3 новости, и создал их 4, то есть 4-ю новость оно скрыло, но пагинацию выводить не хочет. Подскажите, как её вывести.

Comment: Хоть покажите как вы это делаете. Здесь нет телепатов. А на слово, что вы правильно все сделали поверить сложно. Проверяли ли в инструментах разработчика. Блок вообще появляется в коде или нет.

Comment: я же написал что я сделал просто вставил функцию the_posts_pagination() после цикла вывода постов

Comment: так этой функции надо аргументы передать. она сама по себе не работает если ей пустой пользоваться. смотрите [документацию](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination).

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение на wp-kama

```
<?php
// 1 значение по умолчанию
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'category_name'  => 'gallery',
'paged'          => $paged,
) );

// цикл вывода полученных записей
while( $the_query->have_posts() ){
$the_query->the_post();
?>
<!-- HTML каждой записи -->
<?php 
} 
wp_reset_postdata();

// пагинация для произвольного запроса
$big = 999999999; // уникальное число

echo paginate_links( array(
'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) 
),
'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total'   => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```